# How can I include a variable in a Perl printf expression?

Tags: perl, variables, printf, interpolation

How can I include a variable in a printf expression?

Here's my example:

```
printf "%${cols}s", $_;
```

Where `$cols` is the number of columns
and `$_` is a string.

The statement results in an "Invalid conversion" warning.

The problem ended up being that I forgot to chomp the variable. Gah. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Can you please post the full warning text?

Comment: I think the problem is that I am getting the number of columns from the user (STDIN). Here is the full error: 

Invalid conversion in printf: "%\012" at column2 line 28, <STDIN> line 3 (#1) (W printf) Perl does not understand the given format conversion. See perfunc/sprintf.

This is with $cols = 20. But it may actually be $cols = "20"

Comment: So the answer ended up being that I need to chomp the number of columns because it was user input from STDIN and had a newline on the end.

Comment: When you run into these sorts of problems, look at string you are trying to use to ensure it's what you think it is: `print "%${cols}s"`. Most of your programming time will probably be checking values to see that they are what you think they are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out your specific problem. Your code is correct. However, I suppose `$cols` might be a number read from user input, say like this:

```
my $cols = <STDIN>;
```

This works, and in numeric context `$cols` will appear to be a number, but the problem is that `$cols` *isn't* appearing in numeric context here. It's in string context, which means that instead of expanding to `"%5s"`, your format string expands to `"%5\ns"`. The newline there is mucking up the format string.

Change the code where you read `$cols` to this:

```
chomp(my $cols = <STDIN>);
```

See the documentation on [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html), as you may want to use it for other input reading as well.

Comment: This was the answer. I had a new line appended to the end of the user input where the user had input the number of columns. MANY THANKS! :)

Answer (score 11):

Your interpolated variable `$cols` looks like its supposed to be a number, say 10, so

```
"%${cols}s"
```

should interpolate and be equivalent to

```
"%10s"
```

which is a valid format string.

If however `$cols` was something *other* than a number or valid format string, you'd get the warning.

For example, if:

```
$cols = "w";
```

that would result in `"%ws"` as a format string - giving the error you quote:

```
Invalid conversion in printf: "%w"
```

Valid format information can be found [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).

Comment: +1 This is relevant, as it correctly shows the error message. I think I got what the actual problem was, but it's impossible to know without hearing from the OP.

Answer (score 6):

Always use `*` in your format specifier to unambiguously indicate variable width! This is similar to the advice to use `printf "%s", $str` rather than `printf $str`.

From the [perlfunc documentation on `sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html):

> #### (minimum) width
>
> Arguments are usually formatted to be only as wide as required to display the given value. You can override the width by putting a number here, or get the width from the next argument (with `*`) or from a specified argument (with e.g. `*2$`):
>
> ```
> printf '<%s>', "a";       # prints "<a>"
> printf '<%6s>', "a";      # prints "<     a>"
> printf '<%*s>', 6, "a";   # prints "<     a>"
> printf '<%*2$s>', "a", 6; # prints "<     a>"
> printf '<%2s>', "long";   # prints "<long>" (does not truncate)
> ```
>
> If a field width obtained through `*` is negative, it has the same effect as the `-` flag: left-justification.

For example:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $cols = 10;
$_ = "foo!";
printf "%*s\n", $cols, $_;
print "0123456789\n";
```

Output:

```
      foo!
0123456789
```

With the `warnings` pragma enabled, you'll see warnings for non-numeric width arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Your current method should work

```
perl -e'my $cols=500; $_="foo"; printf "%${cols}s\n\n", $_;'
```

Comment: You should test it with `-Mstrict` and `-Mwarnings`, but it does work. Curious why the OP is getting warnings now...

Comment: I did before I posted ;) I didn't want it to look like this answer took me more than 5 seconds. Testing this stuff is *really* simple with Perl, I really don't even have to cut that stuff out to drive my point home.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work for me:

```
#!/bin/perl5.8 -w
use strict;
my $cols = 5;
my $a = "3";
printf "%${cols}d\n", $a;
```

yields

```
28$ ./test.pl
    3

29$
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your problem. The following code works fine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $cols=40;
while (<>) {
    printf "%${cols}s\n", $_;
}
```

It prints any input line using at least 40 columns of width.